# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined (Ionic 3 & Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, viewchild

I have a problem using @ViewChild() on my Ionic 3 application. Indeed, I would like to be able to display a map on the second segment of my page. And I have the following mistake:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Favoris</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
    <div padding>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="view">
            <ion-segment-button value="list">
                Liste
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="map">
                Carte
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div [ngSwitch]="view">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
            <ion-card *ngFor="let favorite of favorites">
                <img src="{{ favorite.photo }}" />
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title>
                        {{ favorite.name }}
                        <ion-icon name="trash" class="icon-remove" (click)="removeFavorite(favorite.id_place)"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <p>
                        {{ favorite.address }}
                    </p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </div>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">
            <div #map id="map" class="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is my TS code:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";

import { GoogleMapsProvider } from './../../providers/google-maps/google-maps';

declare var google: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-favorite',
    templateUrl: 'favorite.html'
})
export class FavoritePage {
    @ViewChild('map') mapRef: ElementRef;
    map: any;
    lat: string;
    lng: string;
    view: string = "list";
    /**
     * a MODIFIER AVEC l'API
     */
    favorites: { id_place: string, name: string, photo: string, address: string }[] = [
        { "id_place" : "9054b4cc53b207424db12d23e1b34b3ae0cfe9c0",  "name": "Café Madeleine Paris", "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMkeDY6tB5bQFEPhy1Ah4HR-2Oh7CjO_td-BbDY=s1600-w400", "address": "1 Rue Tronchet, Paris" },
        { "id_place" : "cf49d5cbc84ecbe0388ef93eb80aa18f9db3ffa9", "name": "Cafe Kitsune", "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNk8GqMTGNo-QF_QwdakFaNvoGwi11tHmY-969p=s1600-w400", "address": "1 Rue Tronchet, Paris" },
        { "id_place" : "b8c6ecc9f9e047dd428f3994c537c3f877ba0e30", "name": "Café des Abattoirs", "photo": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPRKYf0L3uEYzPee5Y7uUBa15Q_7WWtUTWSHvqd=s1600-w400", "address": "10 Rue Gomboust, Paris" },
    ];


    constructor(
        private aFAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public GoogleMaps: GoogleMapsProvider,
    ) {

    }


    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.showMapWithMarker();
    }

    showMapWithMarker() {
        const location = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044);
        const options = {
            center: location,
            zoom: 20
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            title: 'hello world',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
        marker.setMap(this.map);
    }

    removeFavorite(id_place) {
        console.log('Remove favorite : ', id_place)
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can correct this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Call `showMapWithMarker()` only when the map is rendered (i.e. when `view = 'map'` or use map as a default view instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.when your page loaded, the view's value is 'list', the element  map can't render on your page.so the mapRef is null,

2.the quesition is ngSwitchCase,when the ngSwitch value can't match ngSwitchCase,the element will not be rendered.

3.maybe you can  use  directive [hidden] 

  `<div [hidden]="view!='list'"> </div>
  <div [hidden]="view!='map'"> </div>`

Comment: my english is poor,hope you can undstand what did i said

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `view` doesn't match with case that checks if to render map div.

```
view: string = "list"; // it should be "map"
```

---

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">
     <div #map id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
```